# Grails conflict between jQuery Plugin and JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a Grails app that needs jQuery, so I load jQuery and jQuery-UI via plugins:

```
buildConfig.groovy:
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
```

That works fine as far as I don't include a standalone JS-script that also uses jQuery. This script is named myscript.jquery.js and I placed it under web-app/js.

Now I include those plugins and the script in my main.gsp:

```
main.gsp:
<html>
<head>
      ...

<r:require modules='jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap, customcss' />
<g:javascript src="myscript.jquery.js"/>

<r:layoutResources disposition="defer" />

<g:layoutHead/>
<r:layoutResources disposition="head"/>

</head>
<body>
      ...
```

and I get

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
$ = jQuery;
```

Did I make a specific mistake?
Is there a better way to handle this?

PS: I tried to load jQuery directly via script in main.gsp, but that didn't work out because I have other plugins that depend on the jQuery plugin :-/

Comment: take a look at the produced html and see if jquery appears before or after your custom js.  I think the r:require followed by g:javascript may be the cause, try removing jquery from the r:require and define it as g:javascript just above your custom call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your script in ApplicationResources.groovy file located in config and then add that module in the page. This will solve the issue.

Example:
In your conf/ApplicationResources.groovy

```
modules = {
    baseJS {
        resource url: 'js/myscript.jquery.js'
    }
}
```

In your gsp file

```
<r:require modules='jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap, customcss, baseJS' />
```

This is the old blog but you will get the idea

http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2011/09/12/optimising-your-application-with-grails-resources-plugin/

Thanks